# Classification of maps $f:\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{S}^2$ up to homotopy and geometrical meaning.

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

I have two questions.

First, how can one classify maps $f:\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{S}^2$ up to homotopy?

Second, how to interpret geometrically what distinguishes them? I mean, if two maps are non homotopic (let's say they appear to be non homotopic because some invariants distinguish them), I would be really interested in the geometrical interpretation of these invariants. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $M$ is an oriented 3-manifold, then $TM$ is trivial, and so picking a trivialization, a vector field of unit norm is the same as a map to $S^2$. A vector field of unit norm has an orthogonal complement, which is oriented; and changing the map to $S^2$ by a homotopy changes this plane field by a homotopy. So $[M, S^2]$ is oriented plane fields on $M$ up to homotopy.

Comment: I misread this as $S^1 \times S^1$. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A map $\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^2\to\Bbb S^2$ is a free loop in the space of maps $\Bbb S^2\to\Bbb S^2$.

This means that you have to look at

- the set of connected components of maps $\Bbb S^2\to\Bbb S^2$: they are indexed by $\pi_2(\Bbb S^2)=\Bbb Z$. I write "=" rather than "$\simeq$" because the identity map is your favourite generator.
- for each connected component $C_i,\ i\in \Bbb Z$, consider $\pi_1(C_i)$.

To see in which connected component $C_i$ a map $\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^2\to\Bbb S^2$ is, you just need the degree $i$ of the induced map $\{\cdot\}\times \Bbb S^2\to\Bbb S^2$ where $\cdot$ is an arbitrary point of the circle.

Now to compute $\pi_1(C_i)$, I can't see just now how to do that easily for all $i$, but at least it is clear that $\pi_1(C_0)=\{\operatorname{1}\}$, and I believe that one should have $\pi_1(C_1)\simeq\pi_1(SO(3))\simeq \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Good idea. In fact the [space of maps](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0083829) are essentially computed here; for the component of degree $k$ one has $\pi_1 \text{Map}_k = \Bbb Z/2|k|$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Good reference, thanks!

Comment: Thank you all a lot! Could you please explain me why is it obviuos that $\pi_1(C_0)$ is the trivial group? And, also, the intuition between $\pi_1(C_1)=\pi_1(SO(3))?$

Comment: Ok, I think that the first question is obvious because being a degree 0 map gives you the homotopy to the constant loop just by the nullhomotopy. But, I still do not see the intuition behind the equality $\pi_1(C_1)=\pi_1(SO(3))$

Comment: @galois1989 Elements of $SO(3)$ are particular maps $\Bbb S^2\to \Bbb S^2$ of degree $1$, namely isometries. My guts told me that the space of maps of degree $1$ should have the same homotopy type as the subspace of isometries.

Comment: Okey, I see. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: I am confused now. If $\pi_1(C_k)=\mathbb{Z}_{2k}$, then $\pi_1(C_0)$ should not be $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of the trivial one?

Comment: @galois1989 I suspect that this formula holds for $k\neq 0$. I will have a look again at the article later today.

Comment: That would be a nice help Arnaud. I cannot access the free version. Thanks a lot again, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I have just checked it. https://books.google.es/books?id=aIIw5cRra7kC&pg=PA245&lpg=PA245&dq=space+of+maps+s2+s2&source=bl&ots=m5_bszOrzR&sig=VAMEJn5f6dROySPx3QRgrm8MRjU&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3p7ODuqjcAhWDecAKHVouCaEQ6AEwEHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=space%20of%20maps%20s2%20s2&f=false here in page 248 it states a Theorem of Hsu saying that it is the integers for $C_0$.

Comment: @galois1989 Wow, that's surprising. I'll have to read it as right now I can't see how. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! Thanks to you!!

Comment: Sorry. Hu*, not Hsu.